# Why would files appear corrupt but then be fine days later?

Tags: centos, backup, database, corruption

**The Setup:** Dedicated CentOS 7 web server hosting a CRM database on a company’s internal network. Everyday, the server backs up to itself and then the backups are copied offsite.

**The Problem:** This week, the database appeared to become corrupt and couldn’t be repaired. I tried to restore the database from the last backup - the last backup appeared to be corrupt too, as was the day before and the day before that. I start to sweat. Then looked at the offsite backups, which are fine (I’m able to see the data and later use it to restore the database). Did a md5sum of the onsite and offsite backups and they produced different hashes for what should be the same files. Oh, me thinks the server HDD is going bad. The HDD is a RAID5 array of 3 disks with a hardware controller. The array is still showing as clean. Bit odd. Why are remote backups okay but local backups corrupted?

But then...

**4 Days Later:** Presuming that the server is going bad, I’ve started making preparations to migrate to a new server. For no particular reason, I do the md5sum checks again; they are now the same hash onsite and offsite for the files that previously were showing different hashes. As far as I’m aware, nothing else changed on the server in the previous 4 days which would have rectified the previously inaccessible local backups.

Any ideas what’s going on? Is the server breaking or was this just a freak moment and everything is probably fine?